# What is a finitely generated k-algebra and are most objects in introductory algebraic geometry k-algebras?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I am currently learning algebraic geometry and from a set of lecture notes, theorem 4.1 was taken from commutative algebra. I want to ask what is the definition of a finitely generated k algebra and are most of the objects we study in introductory algebraic geometry finitely generated k-algebras which means we are allowed to apply this theorem?

Comment: 1. When you say "from a set of lecture notes", it's a good idea to say which one (and provide a link, if they are online). 2. Did you do any research on your own? For instance, [Wikipedia has a page on finitely generated algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_algebra) which is the first google result for "finitely generated k-algebra". Many abstract algebra books will also define this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A finitely generated $k$-algebra can be described in two ways:

1. A ring $A$ containing $k$ that has finitely many generators as such a ring: there are $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ in $R$ such that $A = k[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$.
2. a ring $A$ that is isomorphic to some $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$: the quotient of a polynomial ring over $k$ in finitely many indeterminates.

**Example**. The "ring of polynomial functions on the circle" is $\mathbf R[u,v]$ where $u^2 + v^2 = 1$ or equivalently (up to isomorphism) it is the ring $\mathbf R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$.